# Android ImageButton in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, imagebutton

I need TableLayout and ImageButton in Java code but there is a problem so i am trying to do like that in xml but I am not understanding why the first button is acting like this.

```
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow>
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/blankc4"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/blankc4"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <ImageButton 
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/blankc4"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/blankc4"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Is there anything i am missing. If not what is the explanation of this output.

I want same button only with and without background color. How to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a backgound set for each one except the first...

If you're looking for just the image as the button, don't use the source tag, but set the background to the image you want.

Comment: I have to change background color in runtime.